# do get() and getline() in c++ treat newline differently?

Tags: c++

```
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;
char ch;
string st;

fin.open("testfile.txt");
fout.open("testfile.txt");
while(!fin.eof())
{
   fin.get(ch);
    cout << ch;
}
fin.clear();
fin.seekg(ios::beg);
while(!fin.eof())
{
   getline(fin, st);
    cout << st;
}
```

Test file contains the following:

```
abcd  efg

1234  hij
```

result:

```
abcd efg

1234 hijabcd  efg1234  hij
```

What I am asking is:

> Why are the results different between reading with fin.get(ch) and
>   getline(fin, st)?

Comment: `while(!fin.eof())` is broken... use `while (fin.get(ch)) ...` and `while (getline(fin, st)) ...`.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`get()` returns every character. `getline()` throws away the line terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `while(!fin.eof())` was broken (see my comment under the question), when you're actually at the end of file you attempt another input operation, and the EOF is *then* set on the stream but not checked until *after* the variable you tried to input to has been used.

That's why you print `st` twice for the last line:

```
1234 hijabcd  efg1234  hij
```

`getline()` does remove the (newline) delimiter from the values set in `st`, which is why all your output will appear on the same line.

For the `get` version the attempted read at EOF returns `Traits::eof()` which you print... that may or may not visibly display something, depending on the `eof()` value your implementation chooses and your terminal/console program.